# Easiest way to add a button on each row of a table HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a table in HTML that as a button on each row that acts a delete button. So when the button is click it will delete the html row as well as a row in the DB. What is the easiest way to do this?

This is what i have so far but it doesn't look good at all:

```
function GetSongs(id) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "Get",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetSongs", "Game")",
        data: { playlistId: id },
        success: function (data) {
            json = data;
            var obj = JSON.parse(json);
            for (var i in obj) {
                songCount++;
                playlist.push(obj[i].SongURL);
                $("#song-table").append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].SongURL + "<button class=" +"editbtn" +">edit</button>"+ "</td></tr>");
            }
            $('#song-count').empty();
            $('#song-count').append('Song Count: ' + songCount);

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my table:

```
<div id="player-playlist" style="height: 300px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x: hidden">
      <table class="zebra" id="song-table" style="width:400px;">
              <tr>
                 <th>Song</th>
              </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any opposition to using a server-side scripting language?

Comment: Where is your attempt to resolve your own issue???

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add delete buttons the same way you're adding edit buttons:

```
$("#song-table").append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].SongURL + "<button class=" +"delbtn" +">delete</button>"+ "</td></tr>");

$('button.delbtn').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGGPZ/2/

Comment: What is this `class=" +"delbtn" +">`? why not just write `class=delbtn ..."`

Comment: @KingKing Just a leftover artifact from copying OP's code.

Comment: BTW, why do we have to bother the `index` while we can use `closest` to get the parent `tr`, so it just need to be `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/qGGPZ/1/

Comment: So i ended up just putting the button in another column like this: $("#song-table").append("<tr><td>" + obj[i].SongURL + "</td>" + "<td><button class=" +"delbtn" +">delete</button>"+ "</td></tr>");

Comment: but this doesnt work for me.             $('button.delbtn').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });

Comment: @user977154 you should delegate event to table level. And before you ask, please search for "delegating event jQuery"

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you!             $("#song-table").delegate("td", "click", function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("delbtn");
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

Answer (score 2):

Give your button an `onclick` Javascript function that includes the `id` as a parameter:

```
"<button type='button' onclick='deleteThisItem(" + id + ")' >delete</button>"
```

Javascript function:

```
function deleteThisItem(theID){
    // ajax call to delete theID from database
    // refresh the table
}
```